# How to integrate HP Quality center with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hp-quality-center

I want to integrate HP qc with my rails application, on linux OS, anybody worked on any api or ruby gem?

Thanks in advance.

Anurag Saxena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this post:

[Rails Activeresource Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221260/consume-non-rails-rest-api-with-activeresource/9423272#9423272)

I have since rewrote the application controller as the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :Sessions

  $HPQC_HOST = "http://hpqc.example.com:8080"
  $HPQC_REST_URL = "#{$HPQC_HOST}/qcbin/rest/domains/<your_domain>/projects/<your_project>"
  $HPQC_LOGIN_URL = "#{$HPQC_HOST}/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate"
  $HPQC_LOGOUT_URL = "#{$HPQC_HOST}/qcbin/authentication-point/logout"


  def allow_cross_domain_access
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "*"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "x-requested-with"
  end

  def getAuthenticatedCurl
    @conn = Curl::Easy.new($HPQC_LOGIN_URL)
    @conn.verbose = true
    @conn.http_auth_types = :basic
    @conn.userpwd = '<your_username>:<your_password>'
    @conn.enable_cookies = true
    @conn.cookiejar = 'cookies.txt'
    @conn.perform #creates the first cookie instance, which allows subsequent calls to the HPQC API
    #return _conn
    puts "connected...."
  end
end
```

Simply put these methods is your RoR app's ApplicationController and then call them from each of your Controllers to access HPQC. Then build an XML request and use the Curl::Easy Gem(i.e., @conn.post_body) to post the request to HPQC.

I plan on building an HPQC Gem to configure and initialize HPQC requests but that'll take me a little time!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are some limitations of the QC OTA library that prevents the direct implementation with ROR. but there seems to be a work-around. Check out the link below.

[Rails App Integration with HPQC (HP Quality Centre)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872668/rails-app-integration-with-hpqc-hp-quality-centre)